# Access function from the inside of an event in a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, this

I've made a plugin contains a click-event and a function:

```
// my function
jQuery.fn.runSlideshow = function() {

  // in here I could write:
  jQuery(this).runSlideshow();
  // to call itself again
});

jQuery(this).find(".navigation-wrap a").click(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  // some code


  // in here, jQuery(this) points to the <a>-tag I clicked on
  alert(jQuery(this).html());


  // but now I want to call the function..
  jQuery(this).runSlideshow(); // won't work
  jQuery.fn.runSlideshow();  // won't work either

})
```

I understand that it can't work right now because in the click event, I'm stuck to refer to the element I clicked on and can't go back to the "function-root". Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: "to call itself again" Why?

Comment: `jQuery(this).runSlideshow(); // won't work` should work though. Are you using two different jQuery versions by any chance?

Comment: dfsq: See it as a looping function with setTimeout's

Comment: Felix Kling: No, only one (1.7.x). Are you sure that it should work? The click event has overwritten the pointer of the outer function as shown with the alert. It'd show the inner html of the a-Tag, not the div-Tag I applied the whole Plugin to, so that's why I assume that it can't find the called function because it is not bound to the a-Tag.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:  See [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJ2PB/2/)

```
// my function
jQuery.fn.runSlideshow = function(i) {
  console.log('in runSlideshow i = ' + i);

  // in here I could write:
  if (i > 0) jQuery(this).runSlideshow(i-1);
  // to call itself again
};

$(".navigation-wrap a").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
  // some code

  // in here, jQuery(this) points to the <a>-tag I clicked on
  alert(jQuery(this).html());

  // but now I want to call the function..
    jQuery(this).runSlideshow(3); //  works
    console.log('call again');
    jQuery.fn.runSlideshow(2);  // works twoo

});
```